# NPM modules suddenly missing: React and React-DOM

Tags: reactjs, npm

So, I've been running this React/Redux App on my local for a bit. Webpack has been watching and node was listening on port 3000.

Did work today, no problem. I installed this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-live-clock

After I did that, I went back and reloaded the app, I got an error about a file missing from the npm modules for React. So I went and looked at the Webpack output in the terminal and found this lovely stack trace:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js 14:12-38
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js 15:12-38
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js 16:12-38
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMTextarea.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactNodeTypes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactNodeTypes.js 14:12-38
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/getHostComponentFromComposite.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMOption.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMOption.js 13:12-38
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/checkReactTypeSpec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/checkReactTypeSpec.js 27:27-70 69:37-80
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInvalidARIAHook.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInvalidARIAHook.js 12:29-72
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDebugTool.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDebugTool.js 14:29-72
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactInstrumentation.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js 27:27-70 35:31-74
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js 24:27-70 40:33-76
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js 13:29-72
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js 11:29-72
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js 17:24-62
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js 13:24-62
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js 17:24-62
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js 16:24-62
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdateQueue.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdateQueue.js 13:24-62
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/traverseAllChildren.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/traverseAllChildren.js 13:24-62
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/getNextDebugID' in '/Users/path/toProject/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js 18:21-56
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./app/index.js
```

I confirmed that they were indeed suddenly missing. So, I reinstalled react and react-dom. No dice.  I went ahead and also uninstalled the Clock npm.

If anyone has any pointers/tricks/hints/suggestions that would be amazing. I'd rather not have to recreate this project with a fresh install of React.

Cheers!

Comment: ah criminy, does it have something to do with this install command? `npm install --save react react-live-clock`

Comment: Is your `react` package in your project the same value as what the `react-live-clock` needs, as pointed here in their package.json https://github.com/pvoznyuk/react-live-clock/blob/master/package.json#L35-L37

Comment: oh, and it looks like I had v15 of React. Looks like I unintentionally screwed up my app by installing that clock package. Because now when I installed React it was v16. Oh boy, what a conundrum. Anyone have any ideas about what I could do or is this just fudged?

Comment: `yarn add react@^15` or `npm i -s react@^15` should work. `react 16` messed a whole bunch of things up.

Comment: @TimRoberts that did the trick. Just what was needed. Many many thanks!

Comment: Can you please write down the answer and marked as answered?

Comment: The solution, at the time was to just run ‘yarn add react@^15’ or ‘npm i -s react@^15’. This solution has more to do with package management and not installing packages that are dependent on other packages. Lesson learned: know your dependents.